# Can Dwolla's Payment Button be used without redirecting to Dwolla's website?

Tags: user-interface, paypal, payment-gateway, user-experience, dwolla

I'm confused on the distinction between Dwolla's "Payment Button" and their "Off-site Gateway". Is the goal of the Payment Button to redirect the user to Dwolla's site, whereas with the Off-site Gateway one can keep the user on the merchant's site through the whole transaction? From [Dwolla's documentation](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs) it is not clear.

If it is not possible for a user to make a payment to a merchant **without** redirecting to Dwolla's website, I would highly recommend this as a feature request.

As an intermediate solution, It would be nice if the workflow when using Dwolla payment button (oAuth) could be condensed from two steps to one. Currently, one must log in and then give their pin, which requires submitting two forms. It would be preferable if this was just one form. This would be a much better UX and further the gap with what Paypal offers.

Comment: This question should not be closed. It's a programming question and Dwolla requires developers to redirect their questions to Stackoverflow. It is not clear to me why Stackoverflow would **NOT** want to be place for **every** website's API questions to be answered. This could have a substantial **worldwide** effect on decreasing API fragmentation/increasing standardization. It's a huge win for everyone in the same way Github's usage of Git helps everyone. Please don't discourage this trend.

Comment: This currently reads like a feature request for the Dwolla developers. We're not their support site, so that doesn't really belong here. Could you rewrite the above to more clearly state just the problem you're trying to solve, and what you've tried so far?

Comment: @BradLarson, fair enough, will do...